# Возвращает среднее значение данного массива, округленное до ближайшего целого числа

Tags: c#, return

> It's the academic year's end, fateful moment of your school report. The averages must be calculated. All the students come to you and entreat you to calculate their average for them. Easy ! You just need to write a script.
> Return the average of the given array rounded down to its nearest integer. The array will never be empty.

Вольный перевод задачи (by @aepot)

> Конец академического года - время расчета среднего балла. Все студенты подходят к вам и очень просят посчитать для них их средний балл. Легко! Вам просто нужно написать программу.
> Рассчитайте среднее значение данного массива, округленное вниз до ближайшего целого числа. Массив не может быть пустым.

Я осмелюсь спросить всех, потому что я не знаю что делать.

Мой код ((

```
    public static int GetAverage(int[] marks)
    {
        public static int[] Arr(int N);
        {
            return marks.Sum();
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            float average = 0.0F;

            for (i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += marks[i];
            }

            average = (float)sum / marks.Length;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Вопрос переведен с английского или другого языка через Google Translate? Если вы знаете русский, приведите текст вопроса в порядок.

Comment: It's the academic year's end, fateful moment of your school report. The averages must be calculated. All the students come to you and entreat you to calculate their average for them. Easy ! You just need to write a script.

Return the average of the given array rounded down to its nearest integer.

The array will never be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так?

```
public static int GetAverage(int[] marks)
{
    return (int) Math.Round(marks.Average(), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Fixed:

```
public static int GetAverage(int[] marks)
{
    return (int)marks.Average();
}
```

Comment: Test Failed
  Should work for 26, 3, 22, 98, 36, 68, 46
  Expected: 42
  But was:  43

Comment: @user425521 Значит у вас неправильное условие и округлять надо не к ближайшему целому, а просто отбрасывать дробную часть путем привдения к `int`, что в английском варианте и указано

Comment: @user425521 Точнее, не приведением к `int`, а через `Math.Floor`

Comment: @SmorcIRL будет ли математически разница между `Floor` и `(int)`?

Comment: @aepot И точно, нету разницы, почему-то вдруг подумалось что оно будет к четному округляться

Comment: @aepot Хотя будет разница когда округляются отрицательные числа, приведение действительно отбросит дробную часть, а `Floor` округлит подальше от нуля, что автору скорее всего не нужно.